# Upgrade .net core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: .net

I have installed VS 2019 with .netcore2.2 and I want to upgrade it .netcore3.0 and I also downloaded and installed Microsoft .NET core SDK 3.0 from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) but still I cannot see ASP.NET core3.0 in project creation.
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio?  That looks like a dropdown, did you click the dropdown and check for its existence in the list?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks Yes I restarted VS and checked it for existence

Comment: Did you also install/upgrade to the new version of Visual Studio 2019 that was released today?  You need to be using at least version 16.3 to get .Net Core 3.0.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I'm using VS version 16.0.0, is it really necessary to upgrade VS to 16.3?

Comment: Yes, it is. Read the yellow box on top of the SDK [download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-windows-x64-installer) page.  It's simply not supported on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the Visual Studio 19 to the latest release 16.3.3 and include the core 3.0 sdk in the vs installer. After updating it, you will be able to view the Core 3.0 template in the drop down. Thanks

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.3.3